# How to determine if a time period is in one or more timeframes with PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have some arrays of information with time periods from a database, and some predefined timeframes. Here is an example:

The predefined timeframes are: 12am-6am, 6am-9am, 9am-5pm, 5pm-8pm, 8pm-12am
My database time period might be: 4:30pm to 8:30pm.

If my database time period stretches over one or more timeframes, I need to split it into chunks. In this case I would need to split 4:30-8:30 into 4:30-5pm, 5pm-8pm, 8-8:30pm, and now have 3 arrays instead of 1. I have further operations to do to the arrays depending on the timeframe.

What I want to know is if the way I've come up with determining which timeframe(s) my arrays belong to a) makes any sense, and b) is the best way to solve the problem.

Here is a small part of my PHP, but you can see my process:

```
// First, a function to determine if a timeframe is between 2 dates, which I found on another SO post:
function date_between($from, $to, $date = 'now') {
    $date = is_int($date) ? $date : strtotime($date); 
    $from = is_int($from) ? $from : strtotime($from); 
    $to = is_int($to) ? $to : strtotime($to);         
    return ($date > $from) && ($date < $to); 
}


$st = $row['Start'];
$end = $row['End'];
$ot_f = date_create_from_format('M j Y H:i:s:uA', $st);
$ot_e = date_create_from_format('M j Y H:i:s:uA', $end);

$timestart = strtotime(date_format($ot_f, 'Y-m-d H:i')); //Start date, formatted
$timestop = strtotime(date_format($ot_e, 'Y-m-d H:i')); //End date, formatted

$timestump = strtotime(date_format($ot_f, 'Y-m-d')); //I take the Y-m-d from the start date, and I will append the assigned timeframes onto them

$six = $timestump + (360 * 60); //'6:00', so this becomes Y-m-d 06:00;
$nine = $timestump + (540 * 60); //'9:00'
$seventeen = $timestump + (1020 * 60); //'17:00'
$twenty = $timestump + (1200 * 60); //'20:00'
$midnite = $timestump + (1440 * 60); //'00:00'

// Start comparing here
if(date_between($six, $nine, $timestart)){ // Does the timeframe start between 6am and 9am?
    if(date_between($six, $nine, $timestop)){ // Does the timeframe end between 6 and 9am?
        // If so, define timeframe. It starts and ends in the same timeframe, so we only have one
        $row['Start'] = $timestart;
        $row['End'] = $timestop;
        $row['Timeframe'] = '6-9am';
    else if(date_between($nine, $seventeen, $timestop)){
        // If so, split the arrays, because now we are talking about multiple timeframes
        $row2 = array();
        $row['Start'] = $timestart;
        $row['End'] = $nine;
        $row['Timeframe'] = '6-9am';
        $row2['Start'] = $nine;
        $row2['End'] = $timestop;
        $row2['Timeframe'] = '9am-5pm';
   } // Continue from here
} else if(date_between($nine, $seventeen, $timestart)){

} else if(date_between($seventeen, $twenty, $timestart)){

} else {

}
```

My code seems really clunky, and this is even streamlined from the first version I wrote. Am I doing this right? Could I make my code better?

Answer (score 0):

Extending this answer a little more, the one main flaw I can see in this code is extendibility. If I wanted to add another time period to check I would have to add more conditional statements and more variables to do so.

If you have a set condition: does `(x -> y)` fall between `(a -> b)` and you have multiple instances of one, or both then you want to use a loop over the multiples and apply the same condition over that loop.

In this instance you have one timeperiod (`$timestart`, `$timestop`) and multiple timeframes, so you would loop over the timeframes, to see if and where your timeperiod fits.

First rather than listing out all the times as variables, I would place them in an array. This makes them loopable and it also allows you to define the start and end points of each, as opposed to writing ever increasing conditions of whether it's between `$six` and `$nine`.

I'd suggest putting the timeframes into an array something along the lines of:

```
$timeframes = array (
    array(
        "start" = "00:00",
        "finish" = "06:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" = "06:00",
        "finish" = "09:00"
    ),
    ...
);
```

You could then use this array to perform your `date_between` check, each element of the array would contain the start and finish times to check as per your current function.

```
foreach ($timeframes as $timeframe) {
    $check_start = $timeframe['start'];
    $check_finish = $timeframe['finish'];

    if (date_between($check_start, $check_finish, $timestart)) {
        // it's a match
    elseif (date_between($check_start, $check_finish, $timestop)) {
        // it's a match
    } else {
        // it's not a match
    }
}
```

However you could avoid doing the additional `elseif` by passing both the `$timestart` **and** the `$timestop` parameters to your `date_between` function.

Comment: So I should modify `date_between` to take 4 arguments, and do the `foreach` after I split the array according to whether it crosses more than one timeframe in the array?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it's a little bit clearer my suggestions are not additions to the code but more improving what is already there.

Comment: Didn't have time today, will test tomorrow. Thanks a bunch!